# How to slice 2d list according to multiple identical first column elements

Tags: python, python-3.x, slice

I'm trying to figure out if there is an efficient way of slicing a 2d-list according to the first element of each inner list, when there are multiple identical first elements.

I haven't used numpy, in fact I've never used it before, but I'm open to it. Honestly, I could come up with a very cumbersome way to do this without it, but I'm hoping for more efficiency.

```
list_to_slice = [[1, 2], [2, 2], [2, 3], [3, 3]]
```

My goal in this example is to slice the 2d list according to the first element. The goal output is:

```
[[1, 2], [2, 2], [2, 3]]
```

EDIT:
Okay, what I want to do is slice all of the inner list elements of the original list with the first element "2". Everything from there to the beginning of the list. The basic command to do so would be:

list_to_slice[0:3]

I'm trying to see if there is an efficient command anywhere, in numpy or elsewhere, to slice the list according to its content and not its location in the list. Like I said, I could probably find a way to do this, I'm just curious if there is a simpler command available in any libraries out there.

Thanks!

Comment: What happened to the fourth list element, `[3,3]`? What does "according to the first element" mean to you? Ordinarily `slice()` takes either one argument, `stop` or three arguments, `start, stop, step`. How are you getting these from the input list?

Comment: Please define properly what you are trying to acheive. IT is not clear how you got that output from the example input list

Comment: Edited to clarify, hope that helps.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[`itertools.takewhile`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools.takewhile) is made specifically for this kind of thing. It will turn your list into an itertator that takes values from the list until a condition is not longer true and then stop:

```
from itertools import takewhile

list_to_slice = [[1, 2], [2, 2], [2, 3], [3, 3]]

sl = takewhile(lambda t: t[0] < 3, list_to_slice) # take items while first element is less than 3
list(sl)

# [[1, 2], [2, 2], [2, 3]]
```

Comment: Exactly what I'm looking for! Thank you very much!

Answer (score 0):

I think you are trying to use the indexes of the first element to select other items in the list. Below is a straightforward solution.

```py
list_to_slice = [[1, 2], [2, 2], [2, 3], [3, 3]]
targets = list_to_slice[0]

result = [targets] + [list_to_slice[targets[0]]] + [list_to_slice[targets[1]]]
print(result)
>>> [[1, 2], [2, 2], [2, 3]]
```

A more general purpose solution

```py
def first_slice(list_to_slice):
    targets = list_to_slice[0]
    result = [targets]

    for target in targets:
        result.append(list_to_slice[target])
    return result

first_slice([[1, 2], [2, 2], [2, 3], [3, 3]])
>>> [[1, 2], [2, 2], [2, 3]]
```